# Visual Studio 2012 Express compiler not linking header files together correctly

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I am setting up some framework for a little 2D game. Right now, I just have a few classes, but I am immediately falling into compiler problems.

I have run this program with only the `main` function, so I can confirm that the Allegro (graphics library) library linking has worked.

I have put all my header files (.h) under the "Header Files" section in the Solution explorer and all my source (.cpp) in the "Source Files" section. I have only modified settings from default as according to this Allegro tutorial: http://wiki.allegro.cc/index.php?title=Windows,_Visual_Studio_2010_and_Allegro_5. It should not have affected anything in a destructive way.

I have several files, so I will list each one. I will skip some code to reduce size and redundancy. When I omit any code or do anything not verbatim, I will put a comment in the code saying so. (EDIT: I actually did not skip any code)

main.cpp

```
#include "common.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   ALLEGRO_DISPLAY *display = NULL;
   World* world = new World(640, 480);

   if(!al_init()) {
      fprintf(stderr, "failed to initialize allegro!\n");
      return -1;
   }

   display = al_create_display(640, 480);
   if(!display) {
      fprintf(stderr, "failed to create display!\n");
      return -1;
   }

   al_clear_to_color(al_map_rgb(0,0,0));

   world->draw(display);

   al_flip_display();

   al_rest(10.0);

   al_destroy_display(display);

   return 0;
}
```

common.h

```
#if !defined(COMMON_INC)
#define COMMON_INC

#include "World.h"
#include "Pane.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <allegro5/allegro.h>

#endif
```

World.h

```
#if !defined(WORLD_INC)
#define WORLD_INC

#include "common.h"
#include "Pane.h"

class World{
public:
    World(int wp, int hp);
    void draw(ALLEGRO_DISPLAY* display);
    void update();


protected:

private:
    Pane* panel;
    int heightPix, widthPix;

};

#endif
```

World.cpp

```
#include "common.h"

World::World(int wp, int hp){
    widthPix = wp;
    heightPix = hp;
    panel = new Pane(this, 10, 10, 300, 400);
    return;
}

void World::draw(ALLEGRO_DISPLAY* display){
    panel->draw(display);
    return;
}
```

Pane.h

```
#if !defined(PANE_INC)
#define PANE_INC

#include "common.h"

class Pane{
public:
    Pane(World* w, int xv, int yv, int wi, int he);
    World* getWorld();
    int getZ();
    void draw(ALLEGRO_DISPLAY* display);
    ALLEGRO_BITMAP* getBackground();

protected:
    void setXY(int xv, int yv);
    void setWidthHeight(int wi, int he);
    void setZ(int zv);
    void setBackground(ALLEGRO_BITMAP* ba);

private:
    int z;
    int x, y; //pixels
    int width, height; //pixels
    World* world;
    ALLEGRO_BITMAP* background;
};

#endif
```

Pane.cpp

```
#include "common.h"

Pane::Pane(World* w, int xv, int yv, int wi, int he){
    this->setWidthHeight(wi, he);
    this->setXY(xv, yv);
    this->world = w;
}

World* Pane::getWorld(){
    return world;
}

void Pane::setXY(int xv, int yv){
    x = xv;
    y = yv;
    return;
}

void Pane::setWidthHeight(int wi, int he){\
    width = wi;
    height = he;
    return;
}

void Pane::setZ(int zv){
    z = zv;
    return;
}

void Pane::draw(ALLEGRO_DISPLAY* display){
    if(background != NULL)
        al_draw_bitmap(background, x, y, 0);
    else{
        background = al_create_bitmap(width, height);

        al_set_target_bitmap(background);

        al_clear_to_color(al_map_rgb(255, 0, 255));

        al_set_target_bitmap(al_get_backbuffer(display));

        al_draw_bitmap(background, x, y, 0);
    }
    return;
}
```

The compiler produces this error report upon building: (I called the game madscientist because it is supposed to be alchemy-themed)

```
1>------ Build started: Project: MadScientist, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  main.cpp
1>c:\users\ethoma\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\madscientist\madscientist\pane.h(8): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'World'
1>c:\users\ethoma\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\madscientist\madscientist\pane.h(9): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
1>c:\users\ethoma\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\madscientist\madscientist\pane.h(9): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\users\ethoma\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\madscientist\madscientist\pane.h(9): warning C4183: 'getWorld': missing return type; assumed to be a member function returning 'int'
1>c:\users\ethoma\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\madscientist\madscientist\pane.h(11): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'ALLEGRO_DISPLAY'
1>c:\users\ethoma\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\madscientist\madscientist\pane.h(12): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
1>c:\users\ethoma\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\madscientist\madscientist\pane.h(12): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\users\ethoma\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\madscientist\madscientist\pane.h(12): warning C4183: 'getBackground': missing return type; assumed to be a member function returning 'int'
1>c:\users\ethoma\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\madscientist\madscientist\pane.h(18): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'ALLEGRO_BITMAP'
1>c:\users\ethoma\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\madscientist\madscientist\pane.h(24): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
1>c:\users\ethoma\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\madscientist\madscientist\pane.h(24): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\users\ethoma\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\madscientist\madscientist\pane.h(25): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
1>c:\users\ethoma\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\madscientist\madscientist\pane.h(25): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\users\ethoma\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\madscientist\madscientist\world.h(10): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'ALLEGRO_DISPLAY'
1>c:\users\ethoma\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\madscientist\madscientist\main.cpp(22): error C2660: 'World::draw' : function does not take 1 arguments
1>  World.cpp
1>c:\users\ethoma\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\madscientist\madscientist\pane.h(8): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'World'
1>c:\users\ethoma\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\madscientist\madscientist\pane.h(9): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
1>c:\users\ethoma\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\madscientist\madscientist\pane.h(9): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\users\ethoma\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\madscientist\madscientist\pane.h(9): warning C4183: 'getWorld': missing return type; assumed to be a member function returning 'int'
1>c:\users\ethoma\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\madscientist\madscientist\pane.h(11): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'ALLEGRO_DISPLAY'
1>c:\users\ethoma\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\madscientist\madscientist\pane.h(12): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
1>c:\users\ethoma\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\madscientist\madscientist\pane.h(12): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\users\ethoma\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\madscientist\madscientist\pane.h(12): warning C4183: 'getBackground': missing return type; assumed to be a member function returning 'int'
1>c:\users\ethoma\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\madscientist\madscientist\pane.h(18): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'ALLEGRO_BITMAP'
1>c:\users\ethoma\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\madscientist\madscientist\pane.h(24): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
1>c:\users\ethoma\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\madscientist\madscientist\pane.h(24): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\users\ethoma\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\madscientist\madscientist\pane.h(25): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
1>c:\users\ethoma\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\madscientist\madscientist\pane.h(25): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\users\ethoma\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\madscientist\madscientist\world.h(10): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'ALLEGRO_DISPLAY'
1>c:\users\ethoma\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\madscientist\madscientist\world.cpp(6): error C2661: 'Pane::Pane' : no overloaded function takes 5 arguments
1>c:\users\ethoma\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\madscientist\madscientist\world.cpp(10): error C2511: 'void World::draw(ALLEGRO_DISPLAY *)' : overloaded member function not found in 'World'
1>          c:\users\ethoma\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\madscientist\madscientist\world.h(7) : see declaration of 'World'
1>  Pane.cpp
1>c:\users\ethoma\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\madscientist\madscientist\pane.h(8): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'World'
1>c:\users\ethoma\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\madscientist\madscientist\pane.h(9): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
1>c:\users\ethoma\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\madscientist\madscientist\pane.h(9): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\users\ethoma\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\madscientist\madscientist\pane.h(9): warning C4183: 'getWorld': missing return type; assumed to be a member function returning 'int'
1>c:\users\ethoma\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\madscientist\madscientist\pane.h(11): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'ALLEGRO_DISPLAY'
1>c:\users\ethoma\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\madscientist\madscientist\pane.h(12): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
1>c:\users\ethoma\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\madscientist\madscientist\pane.h(12): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\users\ethoma\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\madscientist\madscientist\pane.h(12): warning C4183: 'getBackground': missing return type; assumed to be a member function returning 'int'
1>c:\users\ethoma\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\madscientist\madscientist\pane.h(18): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'ALLEGRO_BITMAP'
1>c:\users\ethoma\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\madscientist\madscientist\pane.h(24): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
1>c:\users\ethoma\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\madscientist\madscientist\pane.h(24): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\users\ethoma\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\madscientist\madscientist\pane.h(25): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
1>c:\users\ethoma\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\madscientist\madscientist\pane.h(25): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\users\ethoma\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\madscientist\madscientist\world.h(10): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'ALLEGRO_DISPLAY'
1>c:\users\ethoma\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\madscientist\madscientist\pane.cpp(3): error C2511: 'Pane::Pane(World *,int,int,int,int)' : overloaded member function not found in 'Pane'
1>          c:\users\ethoma\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\madscientist\madscientist\pane.h(6) : see declaration of 'Pane'
1>c:\users\ethoma\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\madscientist\madscientist\pane.cpp(9): error C2556: 'World *Pane::getWorld(void)' : overloaded function differs only by return type from 'int *Pane::getWorld(void)'
1>          c:\users\ethoma\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\madscientist\madscientist\pane.h(9) : see declaration of 'Pane::getWorld'
1>c:\users\ethoma\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\madscientist\madscientist\pane.cpp(9): error C2371: 'Pane::getWorld' : redefinition; different basic types
1>          c:\users\ethoma\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\madscientist\madscientist\pane.h(9) : see declaration of 'Pane::getWorld'
1>c:\users\ethoma\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\madscientist\madscientist\pane.cpp(10): error C2065: 'world' : undeclared identifier
1>c:\users\ethoma\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\madscientist\madscientist\pane.cpp(30): error C2511: 'void Pane::draw(ALLEGRO_DISPLAY *)' : overloaded member function not found in 'Pane'
1>          c:\users\ethoma\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\madscientist\madscientist\pane.h(6) : see declaration of 'Pane'
1>  Generating Code...
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

You have all of the info that I do. I will summarize it for you to save the trouble of looking through everything.

- There are classes separated into header interfaces and source implementations
- common.h is included by all files. It itself includes all of the class definitions in the other header files
- When compiled, the compiler does not recognize classes defined in other header files as data types. Errors, as you would expect, cascade down.
- **The real-time error checker** does not register **any** errors. When hovering over the word "World" when it is used as a datatype in `Pane`, for example, it recognizes the type perfectly. The real-time error checker is the feature that red underlines errors before compiler time.
- This Visual Studio 2012 Express is new except for the modifications mentioned earlier. The project was created as an empty C++ project. Before many headers and sources were add, the `main` function compiled correctly.

Thank you for any responses. If you have any questions, please ask. The problems I have with Visual Studio always irk me.

**EDITS:**

My circular header logic is guarded by the header guards. I don't think this redundancy is a problem.

I tried removing all includes from my header files except for includes to Allegro libraries. This seemed to work better, but there are still weird problems. Why the act of including is causing these data types to error is still a mystery. Here is the new error log:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: MadScientist, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  main.cpp
1>c:\users\ethoma\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\madscientist\madscientist\world.h(16): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
1>c:\users\ethoma\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\madscientist\madscientist\world.h(16): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>  World.cpp
1>c:\users\ethoma\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\madscientist\madscientist\world.h(16): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
1>c:\users\ethoma\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\madscientist\madscientist\world.h(16): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\users\ethoma\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\madscientist\madscientist\world.cpp(6): error C2065: 'panel' : undeclared identifier
1>c:\users\ethoma\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\madscientist\madscientist\world.cpp(11): error C2065: 'panel' : undeclared identifier
1>c:\users\ethoma\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\madscientist\madscientist\world.cpp(11): error C2227: left of '->draw' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
1>          type is ''unknown-type''
1>  Pane.cpp
1>c:\users\ethoma\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\madscientist\madscientist\world.h(16): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
1>c:\users\ethoma\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\madscientist\madscientist\world.h(16): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>  Generating Code...
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

**EDITS ROUND 2:**

I switched my code around so the common.h only includes stdio and Allegro. All the header and source files include common.h and then any class's header file that they are using *individually*. Pane.cpp include Pane.h and common.h. World.h includes Pane.h and common.h.

Error log reads:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: MadScientist, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  main.cpp
1>c:\users\ethoma\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\madscientist\madscientist\pane.h(9): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'World'
1>c:\users\ethoma\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\madscientist\madscientist\pane.h(10): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
1>c:\users\ethoma\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\madscientist\madscientist\pane.h(10): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\users\ethoma\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\madscientist\madscientist\pane.h(10): warning C4183: 'getWorld': missing return type; assumed to be a member function returning 'int'
1>c:\users\ethoma\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\madscientist\madscientist\pane.h(25): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
1>c:\users\ethoma\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\madscientist\madscientist\pane.h(25): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>  World.cpp
1>c:\users\ethoma\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\madscientist\madscientist\pane.h(9): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'World'
1>c:\users\ethoma\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\madscientist\madscientist\pane.h(10): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
1>c:\users\ethoma\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\madscientist\madscientist\pane.h(10): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\users\ethoma\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\madscientist\madscientist\pane.h(10): warning C4183: 'getWorld': missing return type; assumed to be a member function returning 'int'
1>c:\users\ethoma\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\madscientist\madscientist\pane.h(25): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
1>c:\users\ethoma\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\madscientist\madscientist\pane.h(25): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\users\ethoma\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\madscientist\madscientist\world.cpp(7): error C2661: 'Pane::Pane' : no overloaded function takes 5 arguments
1>  Pane.cpp
1>c:\users\ethoma\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\madscientist\madscientist\world.h(16): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
1>c:\users\ethoma\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\madscientist\madscientist\world.h(16): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>  Generating Code...
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

This is how I see my include order now:

1. main includes common
2. common defines COMMON_INC
3. common includes stdio and allegro
4. main includes World.h
5. World defines WORLD_INC
6. World includes common, which is blocked. But this should be okay because common is already included
7. World includes Pane
8. Pane defines PANE_INC
9. Pane includes common, which is blocked. But this should be okay because common is already included.
10. Pane includes World. This is blocked because main already included World. Shouldn't this be okay since World was already included. Why do I even have compiler guards if I need to include files many times over, once for each file that uses it?

**EDITS ROUND 3:**
I have learned a lot from the answers and comments here. It turns out that, according to Wikipedia, "circular dependencies are often introduced by inexperienced programmers who need to implement some kind of callback functionality." The mere fact that Pane uses World and World uses Pane is a design flaw. In Java, this was all fine for me. It was very easy; I thought that this was the best way to notify the entity that "possesses" an object of the object's actions.

It turns out that this is a bad design scheme. Objects should not have dependencies to their "possessors". Instead, I need to implement a observer system, where the Pane can tell the World that it has updated its state.

Reading wikipedia cleared up any questions that I had, so I now consider this question finished. Thanks to the contributors for putting up for a learning programmer.

Comment: There's no mystery whatsoever. You need to pay more attention to the answers. The problem is not that your inclusion is *infinite*. It is not *infinite*, include guards will make sure of that. And that's the only thing they will make sure of. But the real problem is that your inclusion is *circular*. When two files refer to each other, it is impossible to develop a correct linear order of inclusion. It is a chicken and egg problem. Include guards will not help you to solve it. Nothing ever will. It has no solution at all.

Comment: @AndreyT Thank you for your answers. I am starting to think that I have a misunderstanding deeper than the problem at hand. See my most recent update (the include order). EDIT: I do this type of thing in Java all the time, except with no guards because Java doesn't require it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You header files cannot be possibly linked correctly. You included your headers in circular fashion. Your header files include `common.h`, while `common.h` in turn includes other headers, like `World.h` and `Pane.h`.

This is not compilable by any compiler. You have to develop a hierarchy of headers, from low-level headers to high-level headers and make sure that higher-level headers include only lower-level headers. That way you will make sure you have no circular inclusions.

Anyway, why does your `common.h` include `World.h` and `Pane.h`? This looks like an obvious error. `common.h` is intended to be a low-level header. Let `World.h` and `Pane.h` include it, but don't include `World.h` and `Pane.h` into `common.h`.

Note, that header guards do not solve anything in this case. They simply make sure that the inclusion cycle will not get infinite. They break the cycle, but they don't help you to resolve circular dependencies between declarations, if such dependencies exist.

Look what happens in your case when processing `main.cpp`

1. `main.cpp` includes `common.h`
2. `common.h` defines `COMMON_INC`
3. `common.h` includes `World.h`
4. `World.h` defines `WORLD_INC`
5. `World.h` includes `common.h`. **The whole `common.h` is skipped by include guards, because `COMMON_INC` got defined at step 2.**
6. `World.h` includes `Pane.h`
7. `Pane.h` defines `PANE_INC`
8. `Pane.h` includes `common.h`. **The whole `common.h` is skipped by include guards, because `COMMON_INC` got defined at step 2.**
9. `Pane.h` referred to type `World`. Type `World` is unknown, since we haven't gotten to its definition in `World.h` yet. **Error!**

Comment: Very good. I don't quite know how I neglected to see that. I suppose I just assumed that my preprocessor header wrappers were taking care of things, but they do not combat this circular-ness. EDIT: I took more time to look at this, and, since I have the headers included below the guards, it should not be circular.

Comment: `You included your headers in circular fashion`. He has include guards in all the headers - so should it really matter?

Comment: @EricThoma Also, if you only use pointers or references to a class in your header file, you don't need to include the header of that class at all. For example, in Pane.h, you would simply write `Pane(class World* w, int xv, int yv, int wi, int he);` and don't include World.h.

Comment: @user93353: Include guards will simply make sure that the infinite cycle does not take place. Include guards will split the inclusion cycle in some arbitrary place (depending on which header is included first). One header will end up included first and another second. This order of inclusion might end up being incorrect. This is exactly what happens in OP's case and this is exactly why he's getting these error messages.

Comment: @AndreyT I switched my code around. I am putting up the edit for it now.

Comment: @Eric Thoma: "Switching the code around" will only produce a different incorrect order of inclusion, with different error messages - exactly what you reported in your update. You are wasting your time. Get rid of circular inclusions. They achieve nothing.

Comment: @AndreyT I don't understand a way to have includes in each file to every header the I use without circular includes. World uses Pane and Pane uses World. This is excellent help.

Comment: @Eric Thoma - see my answer - I am quite sure it will remove the current errors you are seeing. I have based my answer on the original files you put up.

Comment: @Eric Thoma: You should *never* try to "have includes in each file to every header". That's absolutely useless and meaningless. One more time: you header files have to be stratified, with higher-level headers including lower-level headers, but never the other way around. (Standard library headers are always in the lowest-level strata.) If you have circular dependencies between declarations, they have to be resolved by using forward-declarations, like `class World;` or `class Pane;`. This does not require circular header inclusion.

Answer (score 1):

I think everything will compile even with the circular includes, if you make the following changes

1. In `common.h` you need to rearrange order of headers.

   ```
   #include <allegro5/allegro.h>
   #include "World.h"
   #include "Pane.h"
   #include <stdio.h>
   ```
2. In `pane.h`, after the `#include common.h`, add a forward declaration for `class World`

   ```
   #include "common.h"
   class World;
   class Pane{
    .....
   ```

I think this will make your errors disappear or atleast decrease them substantially.
My answer is based on the original code you put up, not on the Edit.

Comment: While this answer (with the modification of adding a forward declaration of Pane in the World class) fixed all my errors with no other modifications, AndreyT's answer exposed design flaws in my project that I was unaware of. I most certainly will be reforming my code past this point in light of AndreyT's suggestions. Thank you!

Comment: forward declaration of `Pane` in the `World` shouldn't be required because `Pane.h` gets included before `World.h`. Forward declaration should be required in only one of the 2 places. If you need it, that means you have made some change somewhere after you pasted your original code. I can compile your stuff without the 2nd forward declaration.

Comment: I made a change to the include in main without realizing it. This answer is correct as is. Thanks for the answer again. I am sorry I have to choose who to give the check mark to; both answers were helpful.

Comment: @user93353: Forward declaration is the proper approach to resolve such dependencies. But as long as the circular inclusion is there, this will only masquerade over the problem. Tomorrow someone inadvertently changes the order of inclusion in some place of the code, and the errors will appear again. Normal header files never depend on the order of inclusion. And designing them that way is not really rocket science.

Comment: @AndreyT "And designing them that way is not really rocket science." Thanks for the answers, but not really for the passive-aggressiveness throughout.